# Can the Basic Sans Light SF font be use with CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

I was wondering if the San Basic Sans Light SF font be used with CSS? I'm not sure what font family this font belongs too and can't seem to get it to work with CSS. The closest I've got so far is using the sans-serif font family. I was wondering if anyone could guide me on how I could use Basic Sans Light SF in my CSS code.

Thanks, Grant

```
#follower-alert .text {
text-shadow: 5px 0px 5px black;
font-family: sans-serif;

}
```

Comment: You should post your css code so far. How else should be help to find what is wrong with the code?

Comment: About using fonts in the web: always keep in mind that the font has to be available _at the client system_, so where the browser is executed, not on the server side. That means either you use an extremely wide spread font, or you have to pack the font into the web page. That also means you must have a valid license to use it.

Comment: So the browser needs to support the font? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Either the font has to be installed on the client system, or you have to pack and deliver it inside your page, or you have to reference a public URL where the font is available, like google web fonts. You cannot just name a font and expect it is magically available at all browsers by that.

Comment: ahhh ok, I think i get it now, just out of curiosity do you know if Google fonts supports the font I want Basic Sans Light SF? I think a public URL would be the best option.

Comment: Well, take a look yourself! Google for google web fonts! Their site also explains how you can use those fonts in your page.

Comment: I know I was going too, I was just wondering if you knew off the top of your head to speed things up. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, no, never heard of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) property tells the browser to load a font from the operating system. If the browser can't find the font requested, it tries the next one on the list. It it reaches the end of the list, it uses the browser's default font.

What that means is that, when specifying a specific font using the `font-family` property, you are simply requesting that the client use that font *if the client has that font installed*. If you request Helvetica, but the person visiting your site hasn't installed Helvetica, the browser will fall back to the next option.

There are a few keywords that don't specify a specific font, but rather tell the browser to load which ever font it thinks best fits the category. Most browsers load the operating system's default for the specified category. Those keywords (called generic family names) are as follows:

- **serif** - any fairly neutral font that has serifs.
- **sans-serif** - any fairly neutral font that does not have serifs.
- **monospace** - any font in which all characters are the same width.
- **cursive** - any font which simulates handwriting (this is loosely defined).
- **fantasy** - any decorative font with artistic flourishes (this is loosely defined).

Outside of the generic family names, you can specify a specific font in quotes. If you have a font installed on your computer called "Basic Sans Light SF", you can use the following CSS property:

```
font-family: "Basic Sans Light SF", sans-serif;
```

On your computer (and any other computer that has the Basic Sans Light SF font installed), the text will be displayed in that font. On a computer that doesn't have the font installed, some other sans-serif font will be used installed (whatever the OS default is).

**You can get around this limitation using a CSS technique called [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) to embed a web font in your page.**

Embedding fonts in your page [slows down load times](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html) but increases consistency. Because web fonts are a new technology, there are competing file formats which have different levels of support on different devices. For full coverage, the font you use should be optimized for the web, and you should include multiple formats of the same font on your server. You also need to be sure the font you are using is open source or is licensed to you for use on the web.

[Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) offers a large repository of open-source web-ready fonts, hosted through fast CDNs and easily embeddable in any webpage. You may consider using a font available through this service.

If you have a web-ready and licensed font, you can host it on your own web server and use the `@font-face` property manually. Assuming your font files are in a subfolder named "fonts", an example (from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)) is below. This includes all the file formats needed for the maximum possible level of browser coverage. [This page](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/) goes into great detail about the different types of web-font file formats available and the advantages / disadvantages of each.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Basic Sans Light SF';
  src: url('fonts/BasicSansLightSF.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('fonts/BasicSansLightSF.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('fonts/BasicSansLightSF.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/BasicSansLightSF.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('fonts/BasicSansLightSF.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('fonts/BasicSansLightSF.svg#basicSansLightSF') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```